# Is the following inequality correct for finding limit?

Tags: limits, inequality, solution-verification

I have to use the squeeze theorem to solve a limit.

$$\frac{-1}{(n^2+2)^{1/3}}\leq \frac{2+3(-1)^n}{(n^2-2\cos n)^{1/3}}\leq\frac{5}{(n^2-2)^{1/3}}.$$

Comment: Yes, looks correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, that is not correct. Take $n=5$, for instance. Then$$\frac{-1}{\sqrt[3]{n^2+2}}=-\frac13\qquad\text{and}\qquad\frac{2+3(-1)^n}{\sqrt[3]{n^2-2\cos n}}\approx-0.344622<-\frac13.$$

But the second inequality always holds, yes.

You can use the squeeze theorem as follows: for each $n\in\Bbb N\setminus\{1\}$,$$0<\left|\frac{2+3(-1)^n}{\sqrt[3]{n^2-2\cos n}}\right|\leqslant\frac5{\sqrt[3]{n^2-2}}.$$

Comment: Thanks for the correction.

Comment: I'm glad I could help.